# How to add an item into Product collection?

Tags: php, magento

As per the design I need to show Banner image within product listing.

Banner image need to be shown on 6th position(i.e. 2nd row 3rd column) while listing products in Grid view.

**For Example :**

1st Row => **Product__Product__Product**

2nd Row => **Product__Product__[Banner]**

3rd Row => **Product__Product__Product**

What would be the best way to do the same ?

Is there any way to insert custom data into product collection (on 6th position) or anything else I need to do ?

Answer (score -1):

As there is a foreach loop iterating over the product collection in the template

> catalog/product/list.phtml

you can simply build in some checks inside the loop and show your images.

Comment: what is your problem with my answer? do you want copy and paste ready code...you are in the wrong place dude!